# How to make GrpcChannel use HTTP/2 on MonoAndroid?

Tags: c#, android, mono, grpc

I am trying to make request to my server by [MagicOnion](https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion) protocol (it uses transport from gRPC, but deffrent serialization protocol, *message pack* instead of *protobuf*).

An simple test client app, working under `net5.0` is executing code like this:

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
var address = $"http://{ServerUrl.Host}:5002";
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address);
var myServiceClient = MagicOnionClient.Create<IMyService>(channel);
var result = await myServiceClient.GetMyData();
```

...and recieves response succesfully. But if I try to execute the same code on Android app, I am seeing this exception message on server logs:

```cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2ConnectionErrorException: HTTP/2 connection error (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Invalid HTTP/2 connection preface.
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ParsePreface(ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.TryReadPrefaceAsync()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

With logs and traffic dump I can see that the client on .Net 5 uses `HTTP/2`, but on Android - `HTTP/1.1`. As I can see, this is the only deifference between requests.

So, how can I make Android (API30, monoandroid10.0) client use `HTTP/2`?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is to use another gRPCC implementation lib - **Grpc.Core**. It provides `GrpcChannel` class wich is compatible with MagicOnion.
In my case, the library didn't work immediately, throwing the error about `libgrpc_csharp_ext` loading trouble. To solve this, you also have to add pacakge **Grpc.Core.Xamarin**.

The usage example:

```
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ServerUrl.Host, 5002, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
var myServiceClient = MagicOnionClient.Create<IMyService>(channel);
var result = await myServiceClient.GetMyData();
```